# Which link type to use for FeedBurner SmartFeed

Tags: rss, atom-feed

Searching for the correct answer all day, and nobody seems to know, so I thought I'd give it a shot here as a last effort before I keel over.

FeedBurner's SmartFeed service does this:

> Translates your feed on-the-fly into a
>   format (RSS or Atom) compatible with
>   your visitors' feed reader
>   application.

Based on the above information, which would be correct to add to my `<head>` section? The difference being the `type="foo"` sections?

```
<link rel="alternate" href="<?php echo feedburner_url(); ?>"
      type="application/rss+xml" title="FooBar RSS News Feed" />
```

or...

```
<link rel="alternate" href="<?php echo feedburner_url(); ?>"
      type="application/atom+xml" title="FooBar Atom News Feed" />
```

or possibly even both?

Can't find the answer anwywhere. Google (owns FeedBurner), Google groups, FeedBurner help, etc. And FB conveniently doesn't have any type of help system. Maybe that's a hint? =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think you could use either or both at the same time.

What should happen is that the user's feed reader will make an HTTP request with the 'Accept:' header indicating what type of feed it wants (`application/atom+xml` or `application/rss+xml`). Feedburner would then look at the Accept header and serve up the appropriate type for you.

I think you are fine with putting both up. Feed readers are smart enough nowadays to figure out how to get the feed in a format it can easily use.

Comment: That was sort of what I was thinking. Thanks for the input! =)